# Add an Address to the Branch

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add another address to a Branch in 21.203, similar to the how the DefAddress works.  I have extended the Branch DAC and added the field to the extension.  I also tried extending the BAccount DAC and table to get this to work but, nothing is working so far.  The Address record is being created in the Address table but, the PXDBChildIdentity attribute doesn't seem to be sending back the ID to the Address record.  On the screen, when I enter the values for the address, and click Save, all of the values are wiped out and the custom field (UsrCustomAddress) is never populated.

```
#region UsrCustomAddress
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName="Custom Address")]
[PXDBChildIdentity(typeof(Address.addressID))]
public virtual Int32? UsrCustomAddress { get; set; }
public abstract class usrCustomAddress : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrCustomAddress> { }
#endregion
```

And, then, I added the View to the BranchMaint extension.

```
<code>
namespace PX.Objects.CS
{
  public class BranchMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<BranchMaint>
  {

  public PXSelect<Address, Where<Address.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>, 
  And<Address.addressID, Equal<Current<BAccountExt.usrCustomAddress>>>>> CustomAddress;
 }
 }
</code>
```

Not sure what I'm missing?

TIA!

Comment: I opened a case when my solution to your question was not giving expected results. According to Acumatica this is a framework issue that engineering is now aware of and working to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by manually calling .Insert() on the specific Data View in the row inserting event and writing it to the field. PXDBChildIdentity then can update the field with the real identity value (on row persist) after the link is established.

```
    protected void _(Events.RowInserting<Branch> e)
    {
        if (e.Row is null) return;
        Address newAddress = CustomAddress.Insert();

        BranchExt ext = e.Cache.GetExtension<BranchExt >(e.Row);
        ext.UsrCustomAddress = newAddress.AddressID;
    }
```

If anyone knows how to do this in an attribute id love to know. Note, this will only work for newly created records. Any existing records would not have a row inserting event fire and fill your custom field. You need to backfill the data with SQL or just a temporary custom action that you can invoke this code manually.

Comment: Kyle - thanks for sending this over.  I gave it a shot and it doesn't seem to work.  With the code added, I start a new branch, enter the Branch ID, and hit tab -> I'm prompted that my changes will be lost, OK/Cancel.  If I click OK or Cancel, the new Contact and Address records are still not attached to the Branch.

Comment: So if you use the following steps: 1. type new branch ID into the field, 2. edit address line 1 on your new address record joined via an identity and 3. hit save. the address line 1 disappears?